# Function parameters declaration with asterisk?

Tags: c

I do understand generally how pointers in C work, but this line is very mysterious to me:

```
bool lib_aci_open_adv_pipes(const uint8_t * const adv_service_data_pipes) {
..
}
```

What does it mean? Why `*` between var type and `const`? Why two `const`s?

This code comes from an Arduino library.

Comment: A qualifier always applies to the type on the left, unless it is to the left of the base-type, in which case it applies to the base-type. Any question left?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement of asterisk relative to `const` in C matters:

If you want to write that whatever is pointed to is `const`, put `const` in front of the declaration, like this:

```
bool lib_aci_open_adv_pipes(const uint8_t * adv_service_data_pipes)
```

with a declaration like this, an assignment below is illegal

```
*adv_service_data_pipes = 0; // Will not compile
```

but you can change the pointer, for example, by incrementing it:

```
adv_service_data_pipes++; // This is fine
```

If you want to write that the pointer itself is `const`, put `const` after the asterisk, like this:

```
bool lib_aci_open_adv_pipes(uint8_t * const adv_service_data_pipes)
```

Now the compiler allows you to assign `*adv_service_data_pipes = 0`, but disallows `adv_service_data_pipes++`.

If both the pointer and what it points to must be constant, combine the two declarations. This is what your declaration does.

Answer (score 1):

It's a `const` pointer to a `const` value.

The `const uint8_t *` part means that the value the pointer references cannot be modified, while the `const adv_service_data_pipes` means you cannot modify the pointer inside the function.

So, the first part forbids statements like:

```
*adv_service_data_pipes = 0;
```

while the second makes:

```
adv_service_data_pipes += 1;
```

an error.